# Gueant–Lehalle–Fernandez-Tapia formulas for varying volatility

Tags: high-frequency, market-microstructure, market-making, liquidity

There are formulas proposed by Gueant–Lehalle–Fernandez-Tapia related to the optimal bid and ask in market-making models (Optimal Market Making by Gueant or The Financial Mathematics of Market Liquidity). All the formulas are based on the constant volatility and I would like to know if somebody has tried to do research based on the varying volatility.